# hibernate detect cascaded inserts

Tags: java, hibernate

i'm using hibernate to persist my entities. Is there a way to detect if an entity will be newly created within the current transaction? I cannot use `PostInsertEventListener` since i've to add additional elements to the hibernate action queue.

The `PersistEventListener` is not sufficient since it will not detect cascaded inserts.

Comment: Which version of hibernate? And would the hibernate [interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html) help?

Comment: It is hibernate 4.1. Will interceptors be called on cascaded inserts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comment from pd40, i tried to use interceptors. I found out that the interceptor method:

`public Boolean isTransient(Object entity)`

will always be called when an object is newly created even on a cascaded insert.

Since this method will be called **before** `PersistEventLister/MergeEventListener` i have the possibility to add additional elements to the hibernate action queue.

So thanks to pd40 to give me the hint.